# Add column to WebGrid asp.net MVc3.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have created a Webgrid at server side in asp.net Mvc 3.0. The data columns are added there now I want to create columns for Edit and Delete functionality It was created at client side but when I execute It shows only one column which was created for Delete/Edit.Now I want to merge the client side and server side coding (The server side coding is done in class). So Please help me to solve the problem how can I create the grid with all the columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<td class="iconActions">
    <a href='@Url.Action("Details", "Contacts", New With {.id = item.ID})' class="ss_sprite ss_application_view_detail" alt="View Detail" title="View Detail" />
</td>
<td class="iconActions">
    <a href='@Url.Action("Edit", "Contacts", New With {.id = item.ID})' class="ss_sprite ss_application_edit" alt="Edit" title="Edit" />        
</td>
<td class="iconActions">
    <a href='@Url.Action("Delete", "Contacts", New With {.id = item.ID})' class="ss_sprite ss_cross" alt="Delete" title="Delete" />
</td>
```

---

In my case, @Url.Action was used because I wanted icons instead of worded links and needed to do that with css classes.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Can u send me the code of edit and delete. The data has to be edit and delete in Sql server

Comment: Is this possible using Webgrid?

Comment: The edit and delete are handled by the controller action code. As far as the webgrid, I tend to stay away from it and build my "grids" myself.